# Chrome Extension : Issue with SendMessage

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to change the contents of a page based on the output of a xhr call. I am sending a message from content.js making the xrh call in the background js file and then passing the output to content.js which alters the content of the page.

From my `content.js` file I am doing the following.

```
var s = document.createElement('script'); 
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('src/content/main.js'); 
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

In my `main.js` I am doing

```
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    method: 'GET',
    action: 'xhttp',
    url: myurl
  }, function(responseText) {
      console.log("Response Text is ", responseText);
  });
```

And in my `bg.js` I have the following

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, callback) {
    if (request.action == "xhttp") {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var method = request.method ? request.method.toUpperCase() : 'GET';
        xhttp.onload = function() {
            callback(xhttp.responseText);
        };
        xhttp.onerror = function() {
            // Do whatever you want on error. Don't forget to invoke the
            // callback to clean up the communication port.
            callback('Error');
        };
        xhttp.open(method, request.url, true);
        if (method == 'POST') {
            xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        }
        xhttp.send(request.data);
        return true; // prevents the callback from being called too early on return
    }
});
```

The issue I am facing is I keep getting the error `Invalid arguments to connect.` for `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` function.

I am not sure what I am missing. Any help us is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you inject the `content.js` code? I don't see any immediate errors with your code, and I've never seen such an error - sounds like using `connect` instead of `sendMessage`.

Comment: @Xan I was using the following in content.js and had the remaining logic in main.js as I wanted jQuery to be loaded before executing the script. Looks like that was causing the issue. Now I moved it to content.js it works fine.
`var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('src/content/main.js');
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);`

But however I can't use jQuery now. Any idea for fixing that?

Comment: Aha, so my theory is correct.

Comment: @Xan Thanks for pointing that out. Any idea, why that won't work? Post it as an answer so that I can accept it. 

Also do you have any idea how to fix the jQuery not loaded issue?

Comment: I will. Can you edit this information into the question itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have been trying to inject your content script into the page with a `<script>` tag.

When you do it, your script ceases to be a content script: it executes in the context of the page, and loses all elevated access to Chrome API, including `sendMessage`.

You should read up on [isolated world concept](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script) about page-level scripts.

To use jQuery, you should not rely on the copy provided by the page - it's in another context and therefore unusable. You need to include a local copy of jQuery with your files and load it before your script:

1. If you're using the manifest to inject scripts, you can add jQuery to the list *before* your script:

   ```
   "content_scripts": [
     {
       matches: ["http://*.example.com/*"],
       js: ["jquery.js", "content.js"]
     }
   ],
   ```
2. If you are using programmatic injection, chain-load your scripts to ensure the load order:

   ```
   chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "jquery.js"}, function() {
     chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "content.js"});
   });
   ```

Comment: P.S. To explain the error message: web pages can, [in some circumstances](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage), call `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`, but require an additional argument (extension/app ID). Not a very intuitive error.