# chrome.storage.sync.get from web page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hello guys,

I want to be able to access informations stored in chrome.storage.sync from an inline script within a web page, injected by my extension.

When trying to use chrome.storage.sync, sync can't be called from "undefined". In the same way, I couldn't call chrome.runtime.sendMessage. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29601868/1928380) taught me I can't access Chrome APIs from an injected script.

I found out that I could eventually call sendMessage using this technique : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage and then I could return the wanted data in the callback.

But I wanted to know, is there a better way to do this ? Accessing chrome.storage data from the injected script ? The fact that I need to use my extension's as an argument is really not great...

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your injected script is essentially the same as the page's own code from a security perspective, there's no way to make this task easy.

`externally_connectable` that you found is one of the ways to do it.

The other way is to talk with the content script itself. You can do so with [custom events or `window.postMessage`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25838804/gmail-extension-sendmessage-to-background-from-page-context/25847017#25847017).

Comment: Thanks, custom events seems perfect !

Comment: Just beware that the page's own code can spoof it, in theory.

Comment: Sure. I will add some security checks. Is it possible to get a callback or use a promise to make use of return values ?

Comment: Yes, something like a self-deregistering listener (listen for specific message, run `removeEventListener` with a reference to self) can be put in a promise.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're very kind but I didn't get that hint. I don't succeed in returning to the injected script the data retrieved by the contentScript, not with a callback nor with a promise :(

Comment: Make a new question with your requirements (communication from an injected script to the content script with a response as a promise) and we'll figure something out. It'll help others as well.