# Chrome extension - pass data from content_script.js back to web page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension I'm working on.  My background.js script does something and returns a string (backgroundResponse) back to my content_script.js.  This works fine as shown here:

webpage (index.html):

```
jQuery("#clickmenow").on("click", function (event)
{
   document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('funcDoRequest', {
      'detail': { task: 'dir' }
   }));

   // I want backgroundResponse here instead somehow..?
});
<a href="#" id="clickmenow">Click me now</a>
```

background.js

```
document.addEventListener("funcDoRequest", function (stuff)
{
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(stuff.detail, function (backgroundResponse)
    { alert('Returning data from background.js: ' + backgroundResponse); });
});
```

My problem is I would like the response backgroundResponse to be returned synchronously to the calling jQuery on click somehow.  So when someone clicks #clickmenow it ends up running my background.js stuff, and returns the value all the way back to the onclick (or dispatchEvent), not just to content_script.js which is what it is doing now.   How can I do this?  I can't figure it out.

Comment: That should be your _content.js_

Answer (score 0):

> I would like the response backgroundResponse to be returned **synchronously**

That's not going to be possible - any communication with the background page is going to involve async messaging.

---

Event-based communication can't use explicit responses, but you can just as well [trigger another event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33999864/934239) that the page listens to. You can include some sort of unique ID that the content script must copy to the response to differentiate between events.

---

Finally, if that's a webpage you control on a domain you know in advance, consider using [`externally_connectable`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) and speaking to the background page directly.

Answer (score -1):

both content script and background page can use chrome.runtime.sendMessage api to communicate

```
//content script
jQuery("#clickmenow").on("click", function (event) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({'detail': { task: 'dir' }}, function (backgroundResponse) { alert('Returning data from background.js: ' + 
       // handle backgroundResponse
    });

});


//background page

  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(detailFromContentScript, sender, sendResponse) {
    // handle detailFromContentscript
    var backgroundResponse = process(detailFromContentScript)

    // then send back response to content script
    sendResponse(backgroundResponse)
})
```