# Chrome extension communicate between injected script and popup.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a chrome extension in which I inject serveral different scripts which may potentially need to share data.  I am trying to use message passing as described [here](http://I%20am%20trying%20to%20write%20a%20chrome%20extension%20in%20which%20I%20inject%20serveral%20different%20scripts%20which%20may%20potentially%20need%20to%20share%20data.%20%20I%20am%20trying%20to%20use%20message%20passing%20as%20described%20here:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33063774/communication-from-an-injected-script-to-the-content-script-with-a-response/33064000#).

I can send a message from one of the injected scripts to another, but I can't seem to be able to send anything back to the extension.

Code in the extension popup.js:

```js
function injectLoad() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        // query the active tab, which will be only one tab
        //and inject the script in it
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "load.js"});
    });
}

function  initPopup(  ) {
    console.log( "starting" );
    window.addEventListener( "something", function( evt ) {
      alert( "got " + evt.detail );
    }, false );
}

document.getElementById( 'loadit' ).addEventListener( 'click', injectLoad );

initPopup();
```

Code in the injected script:

```js
function loadit() {

    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("something", {data: 'whatever'}));
}

loadit();
```

I never seem to get the event triggered.  Thanks

Comment: See the [architecture article](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) - the popup is a separate page. Use [extension API messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: Also you don't need to use `chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}` in the popup in order to get the tab.id for the `chrome.tabs.executeScript`, you can just pass `null` as the parameter to it which then defaults to the active tab of the current window.